# How do you use the sprs_ldl crate to solve a linear system?

Tags: math, rust, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, rust-crates

I am looking at the sprs crate and trying to figure out how to actually use it. I have made a sparse matrix and a sparse vector now I need to actually solve the system.

The documentation mentions that you can solve through `sprs-ldl`, but if you go to that create there are no examples showing how to use the library. The `new` method of the Ldl object takes no parameters.

One would assume that `ldl_lsolve` is the correct method to use, except it consumes the rhs vector, does not return anything and seems to assume the input matrix is already factored into an ldl form?

This is all very confusing.

Comment: `Ldl` is a "Builder pattern structure to customize a LDLT decomposition" use `numeric()` to calculate the decomposition and `LdlNumeric::solve()`‽

Comment: @cafce25 That's what I don;t understand Ldl takes no parameters, how do you use it to compute the decomposition?

Comment: `numeric`  takes 11 parameters. I am sorry but I am not putting the effort to figure 11 parameters out when libraries like Eigen can do this in a much simpler fashion in C++

Comment: Wdym [`numeric()`](https://docs.rs/sprs-ldl/latest/sprs_ldl/struct.Ldl.html#method.numeric) takes 1 parameter (in addition to the builder), the matrix to compute a LDLT off.

Comment: A [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) (`Ldl`) is a helper struct to configure the specifics of how to compute the LDLT in this case, it does *not* itself compute the LDLT. You do so using it's methods `check_*()` and then finally call `numeric()` to do the actual work.

Comment: Under the assumption that the default construction to Ldl works. the numeric method returns an LdlNumeric, but the solve method expects a matrix view. Do you know how to turn things back into a amtrix?

Comment: Have you tried `to_owned` to turn it to something owned?

Comment: I don;t think that;s the issue, LdlNumeric is a fully fleshed struct, not a reference nor a wrapper, `let l: CsMat<_> = ldl.numeric(l.view()).unwrap().to_owned();` just complains about the types not matching.

Comment: Don't add a useless (and wrong) type annotation?

Comment: It is the exact same problem without the type annotation. The LdlStruct and the matrix types are distinct things and you cannot pass one as a stand for the other.

Comment: Ah yea because `LdlNumeric` is the composition, you want to call `solve()` or `l()` or `d()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to go about this seem to be:

```rs
    use sprs::{CsMat, CsVec, TriMat};
    use sprs_ldl::*;
    
    let mut expandend_matrix = TriMat::<f32>::new((3, 3));
    for i in 0..3
    {
        expandend_matrix.add_triplet(i, i, 2.0);
    }

    let rhs = CsVec::new(3, vec![0, 1, 2], vec![1.0, 1.0, 1.0]);

    let l: CsMat<_> = expandend_matrix.to_csr();

    let ldl = Ldl::default();

    let system = ldl.numeric(l.view()).unwrap();
    let sol = system.solve(rhs.to_dense());

    println!("{}", sol);
```

Which in my case prints:

```
[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
```

As expected.

Kudos to cafce25 for figuring this out.